# Why this javascript code with 2 conditions not works?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function deletevalueuser(){
  if(document.getElementById('user').value=='Usuario'){
    if(document.getElementById('user').style.color=='#C0C0C0'){
      document.getElementById('user').value='';
      document.getElementById('user').style.color='black';
    }
  }
}
```

thats the javascript code that shoulds only delete the content of the input if the user havent writte anything

Comment: Is the user , a div or an input field?

Comment: its an input feld with an id with user

Comment: Provide sample HTML that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Show us ur html as well pls

Comment: <input id="user" type="text" value="Usuario" onfocus="deletevalueuser()" onblur="insertvalueuser()" />

Comment: I'll bet good money that if you console.log the `style.color` value, it's actually an RGBA value, and not even close to the hex value you're checking for.

Comment: @adeneo yup , I am pretty sure

Comment: but normally hex always have work, i dont know why yet no

Comment: Because browsers convert that to a format they like best internally, and then return that when you “query” the value via `element.style`. However, this whole problem disappears, once you do it “properly” and set classes instead of manipulating styles directly.

Comment: How about accepting the answer the helped you the most?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should compare the color codes on their hex value , so try rgb.

Note: rgb of #c0c0c0 is 192,192,192

```
function deletevalueuser(){
 var compare = "rgb(192,192,192);"
  if(document.getElementById('user').value==='Usuario'){
    if(document.getElementById('user').style.color===compare){
      document.getElementById('user').value='';
      document.getElementById('user').style.color='black';
    }
  }
}
```

I also read somewhere that the browser reads the hex code in lower case so you may want to try this also:

```
function deletevalueuser(){
 var compare = "rgb(192,192,192);"
  if(document.getElementById('user').value==='Usuario'){
    if(document.getElementById('user').style.color==='#c0c0c0'){
      document.getElementById('user').value='';
      document.getElementById('user').style.color='black';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @KevinAntolinezMiranda k try it and let me know

Comment: I would not bet on every browser returning the same “format”. If anything, you should get your initial compare value by reading the style of an element that has that color set. (But as said in comment above before, the proper way to do this would be by manipulating element _classes_, not element styles.)

Comment: @KevinAntolinezMiranda edited my answer , try option number 2

Comment: but it's usually better to check for classes instead of colors

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because you are using hex value #C0C0C0
and the code retrun rgb value:

Here's a working demo:

```js
function deletevalueuser(){
  console.log(document.getElementById('user').style.color);
  if(document.getElementById('user').value == 'Usuario'){
    if(document.getElementById('user').style.color == 'rgb(192, 192, 192)'){
      document.getElementById('user').value='';
      document.getElementById('user').style.color='black';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input onfocus="deletevalueuser()" type="text" value="Usuario" style="color:#C0C0C0" id="user">
```

Comment: Haha , I was a few seconds faster . But still this is the answer so plus one!

Comment: @KevinAntolinezMiranda which browser are u using?

Comment: This **is** not the answer, comparing colors is a horrible idea, as some browsers will return hex, others RGB, and the latest browsers will return RGBA, you never know

Comment: Well his question isn't about how to comapre colors across browsers... it's about conditionals.

Comment: If you asked me i'd say that you are doing the whole thing wrong. Why use javascrip when the `placeholder="type your username"` attribute is perfect for that?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any documentation to back this up, but it seems that IE, Chrome and Firefox all return the `style.color` property as an RGB value, so I would advise comparing against that:

```
function deletevalueuser(){
  if(document.getElementById('user').value === 'Usuario'){
    if(document.getElementById('user').style.color === 'rgb(192, 192, 192)'){
      document.getElementById('user').value = '';
      document.getElementById('user').style.color = 'black';
    }
  }
}
```

Note the spaces between the values. All three browsers seem to be consistent on the use of spaces there as well.

On the other hand, given that this is a rather shaky way of checking whether an element is in a particular state (doesn't take computed styles into account, for example), I would advise using some other criteria to perform your check (such as the presence of a class, etc.).

Comment: also make the first if check as `===`

Answer (score 0):

I can tell what you're probably trying to do, and here's an easier solution to achieve the same thing:

```html
<input id="text" value="" placeholder="Usuario" />
```

The `placeholder` tells the browser to do almost exactly what your JavaScript code does: show some grayed out placeholder text (`"Usuario"`) when the input field is empty.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly, thank all of you i have learned new thinks

Answer (score 0):

Working [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/4feh71y6/1/)

There are a number of possible problems here.

1. getting  `style.color` won't return anything if the style is
   specified in css. you need to use `getComputedStyle()`
2. If you received a color it probably will be in rgb format so you have to
   convert it to hex

   ```
   function deletevalueuser(){
     el=document.getElementById('user');

     if(el.value=='Usuario'){
       cel=getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('user'), null);
       if(rgb2hex(cel.color).toUpperCase()==='#C0C0C0'){
         el.value='test';
         el.style.color='black';
       }
     }
   }
   deletevalueuser();
   ```

here is the function to convert rgb to hex

```
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    if (/^#[0-9A-F]{6}$/i.test(rgb)) return rgb;

    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    function hex(x) {
        return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}
```